# Anylogic - Model don't run in Browser Mode

Tags: mysql, anylogic

I have created a model in Anylogic 7 which get some values from my localhost mysql database. It runs when I export it at stand alone mode but when I am testing it at browser mode i got the error msg:

```
CacheEntry[http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/supply/com.xj.anylogic.engine.jar]:       
updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 24 08:33:50 EEST 2014,length=1401999
CacheEntry[http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/supply/model.jar]: 
updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 24 08:33:50 EEST 2014,length=471484
0
CacheEntry[http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/supply/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar]:    
updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 24 08:33:50 EEST 2014,length=959987
Error during model creation:
ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:307)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.xj.anylogic.engine.connectivity.Database.a(Unknown Source)
at com.xj.anylogic.engine.connectivity.Database.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at supply_chain.Factory.instantiateBaseStructure_xjal(Factory.java:1409)
at supply_chain.Factory.<init>(Factory.java:1394)
at supply_chain.Main.instantiate_factory_xjal(Main.java:589)
at supply_chain.Main.instantiateBaseStructure_xjal(Main.java:2863)
at supply_chain.Main.<init>(Main.java:2850)
at supply_chain.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:3399)
at supply_chain.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:1)
at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Experiment.a(Unknown Source)
at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.b(Unknown Source)
at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
at supply_chain.Simulation.executeShapeControlAction(Simulation.java:900)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied    
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:118)
... 16 more
```

I don't understand where is the error. Can't connect to MySQL because of JAVA security policies?

Answer (score 0):

You are very restricted when using Anylogic in an web applet. 
if you look in the anylogic help file, [Anylogic help](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/standalone/Running%20a%20Model%20as%20Java%20Applet.html)
it states:

> According to the Software License Agreement, you may not access any kind of databases or files from Simulation Applets.

so it seems that you have to hardcode the data into the model

Comment: Yes, though this is an AnyLogic restriction rather than a Java applet one. Applets *can* be made to be able to read/write to files and databases (which requires complicated Java security configuration); it's just that AnyLogic exports them in a way which doesn't have this set up (because it's complicated with lots of model-specific---and probably environment-specific---detail). (At least that's my understanding; I keep meaning to test whether I can get such an exported applet working...) If you have access to a Java applets expert it may be possible to get it working.